# Is the Lebesgue measure of Borel subsets "regular" w.r.t Jordan-measurable subsets?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\lambda^d$ denote the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Is it true that for any Borel subset $A$, there exists a sequence of Jordan-measurable subsets $B_1, \dots$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda(A \Delta B_n) = 0$$

My guess is that the answer to the above is "yes", as it holds for the examples I can think of, such as the rational numbers and the fat cantor set. If the answer to the above is "no", does it hold for open sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\lambda$ is outer regular, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is an open $U$ such that
$$\lambda(A \triangle U) < \epsilon/2.$$
There is a sequence of $V_1,V_2,...$ of open balls such that $U = \bigcup_j V_j$. The boundaries of open balls have measure $0$. Because $\partial(A \cup B) \subset \partial (A) \cup \partial (B)$, the boundary of $W_n=\bigcup_{j=1}^n V_j$ has measure $0$ for every $n$. Then,

$$\lambda(A \triangle W_n) \leq  \lambda(A \triangle U) + \lambda(U \triangle W_n) < \epsilon$$

for large enough $n$ because $\lambda(U \triangle W_n) \to 0$.